# How to add 3 ng repeats inside table body?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a table with 3 ng -repeats basically I want to repeat the tbody inside same table :

I tried :

```
<tbody ng-repeat="itemName in items" ng-if="(option === 'a' && isMetrics(itemName))">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="{{results.length + 1}}">{{itemName}} </th>
  </tr>

  <tr ng-repeat="n in controlTest.test[currentTest][segment1][segment2][segment3][itemName]">
    <tr ng-repeat="subcategory in controlTest.test[currentTest][segment1][segment2][segment3][itemName][n]">

      <td style="font-weight: bold" class="ignore"> {{check}}
        <result-test-comparator-detail-table controlTest="controlTest" results="results" descriptor="'@'+n+':'" name="subcategory" metric="itemName" k="n" subcategory="subcategory"></result-test-comparator-detail-table>
      </td>
      <td style="display: none">{{subcategory}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="result in results" ng-style="getStyle(true, result, 'offerXentityTypeCountsAtK', n, subcategory)" ng-show="result.test">
        {{getPath(result, itemName, n, subcategory) ? (getPath(result, itemName, n, subcategory) | number:3) : (getPath(result, itemName, n, subcategory) == 0 ? 0 : "N/A")}}
        <span style="float: right; display: block">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" style="color: limegreen" ng-if="getPath(result, itemName, n, subcategory) > getPath(controlTest, itemName, n, subcategory)">{{percentDiff(result, controlTest, itemName, n, subcategory) | number:3}}%</span>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" style="color: red" ng-if="getPath(result, itemName, n, subcategory) < getPath(controlTest, itemName, n, subcategory)">{{percentDiff(result, controlTest, itemName, n, subcategory) | number:3}}%</span>
        </span>
      </td>
      <td ng-repeat="result in results" ng-hide="result.test" class="ignore">
        <img src="img/progress.gif" class="when-not-loaded-layout-img" alt="Loading..." height="10" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

But Nothing shows up other than the itemName. Can somebody let me know how do I do this?

Comment: try to change the element of second `ng-repeat` from `tr` to `div`.

Comment: You can't nest `<tr>` in a `<tr>`

Comment: Do you mean you need one TR for "n" and another TR for "subcategory"?